# Python Increment Floating Number 1.9 to 1.10 instead of 2.0

Tags: python, floating-point, increment

I'm trying to increment a floating value of 1.9 to 1.10. My logic is if value == 1.9 then increment by 0.10, but that keeps bringing it to 2.0.

Does anyone know the logic to have it show 1.10 instead?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Perhaps you don't want floats at all, you want a string with two ints separated by a dot. If you are dealing with version numbers, don't try to make them be a float.

Comment: 1.9 = 19/10 > 11/10 = 1.10

Comment: str(float(line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0]) + 0.1)

Comment: @user3495404 It's simple. Don't use `float` for version numbers. They're *not* floating-point numbers.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart so what else can I use here? If I remove the float it blows up on me.

Comment: You should really show what the input string actually looks like when you run it, not the empty `"$Revision: "`  Right now, this appears to be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Input string: -- CVS Header: $Source: /CVS/oracle11i/database/erp/apps/pkgspec/wwt_prime_pkg.pls,v $, $Revision: 1.14 $, $Date: 2014/09/23 21:41:15 $

Comment: @JonathonReinhart This is all one string I'm picking apart and updating. I could not find another way to update the Revision number (1.x) other than converting to a float. Let's leave the preaching out of this.

Comment: Just add `split('.')` and convert with `int()`, like I've shown below.

Answer (score 3):

1.9 + 0.1 does not equal 1.10.

If you want these semantics, you probably shouldn't be using floating point numbers (as they rely on standard math working correctly.)

Rather, store your components as a pair of `int`s.

For example:

```
ver = "1.9"
ver = [int(x) for x in ver.split('.')]
print 'Version {0[0]}.{0[1]}'.format(ver)    # Prints  "Version 1.9"

ver[1] += 1
print 'Version {0[0]}.{0[1]}'.format(ver)    # Prints  "Version 1.10"
```